# Reference a Main_Dataset in a subDataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to reference my MAIN dataset in a Jasper .jrxml when querying for my subdatasets.

I have about a dozen sub-datasets that all rely on the main set, in the following way:

```
SELECT
what_i_need,
for_my,
subdataset
FROM
(my main dataset which has a fairly long query) m
group by m.sth
order by 3,4 desc, 2;
```

What that does is query the main and then use that as a table to query for the subs, but the drawback is that I have to change every subdataset manually every time I need to change the main

I'm aware that I *COULD* go for creating a view in the database and then simply referencing that from inside Jasper for both main and subs.
(And also changing the view definition as needed)

I'm asking whether Jasper can be "taught" how to use the entire main dataset as a parameter for the subdatasets?
The goal is to set all the subdatasets once with some sort of parameter, and only change the main, and have the expected results.

The end goal should be something like this:

```
SELECT
what_i_need,
for_my,
subdataset
FROM
$P{Main_Dataset} m
group by m.sth
order by 3,4 desc, 2;
```

Comment: For what are sub-datasets? *List Component* or *Subreports* or *JasperFillManager* or other?

Comment: Charts with a subset for each and all with a single parameter from the main dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add String parameter to your dataset, let's say `pQuery`.

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ( $P!{pQuery} ) m
  GROUP BY ...
  ORDER BY ...
```

Exclamation `!` char is important.

In chart's datasource:

- *Use connection expression* with default value `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}`.
- Add `pQuery` parameter and set expression as `$P{JASPER_REPORT}.getQuery().getText()`

Comment: This works exactly as specified, only I spent more hours than would be sane to admit trying to figure out why it wouldn't work.

Note:

Make sure you don't close your main dataset query with a semicolon like I did, or else you'll be spending days and nights in futility.